# mock not creating rpm package with --scm-enable

Tags: git, mocking, fedora

I have been trying to create an rpm package using git with mock. Here is the command I am running:

```
mock -r fedora-22-x86_64 --scm-enable --scm-option method=git --scm-option package=package_name --scm-option git_get='git clone repo_name SCM_PKG' --scm-option --spec='package_spec' --scm-option branch=master --scm-option write_tar=True -v
```

Now, in my result I can only see source rpm. I don't see any rpm inside RPMS/ directory. Further investigation showed that mock is running "rpmbuild -bs" instead of "rpmuild -ba". While I run mock with created source rpm, I have been able to create RPM package properly.

Can you please help me out to understand what am I doing wrong here? How do I tell mock to create RPMs and not just only SRPMs? Or does mock-scm only creates SRPMs?

Comment: Okay, so turns out it's a bug: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1190450 but I don't know how to apply that patch. I mean which mock.py do I make those changes and will they reflect just by changing that mock.py? Sorry, I am a newbie to open source world.

Comment: My [comment to my answer on your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29603207/adding-a-patch-using-mock#comment47509140_29661493) explains how to add a patch to the mock RPM locally.